# past simple vs past continuous (Interrupted event)?

Tags: past-continuous

What's wrong with this sentence ?

Last night ,I was being a little sleepy when my friends called me !

according to this article : [FUNCTIONS OF THE PAST CONTINUOUS](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/past-continuous-tense/)

> to describe an unfinished action that was interrupted by another event
>   or action, e.g. "I was having a beautiful dream when the alarm clock
>   rang."

Comment: No one says *I was being (a little) sleepy*, because "[a]djectival predicates can be cast in the progressive if they're [volitional (sense 2)](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/volition)"—as per [this great answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/132154/3395) by [snailplane](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/230/)—which *be a little sleepy* isn't.

Comment: I was a little sleepy when my friends called me ! ... is it correct grammatically !!

Comment: Yes. By the way, people usually terminate sentences with periods, not exclamation marks, unless they're excited or shouting. Further, don't put a space before a punctuation mark: *How are you ?* should be *How are you?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sleepy` isn't used with being. You would say

```
Last night, I was sleepy when my friends called me.
```

More details, this great answer [stative vs dynamic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/132154/41529)